# Django - Transfer data from view to form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am struggling with the update of database information with the forms, and simply passing information between views. I could really use some advice because I am fairly new to Django.

The flow goes like this:

**1.** First form; I transfer the article price and title to the view "event"

[image: html_1]
[image: Rendering of the html]

**2.** The view "event" handles title and price and ask for confirmation in the html form

[image]

[image]

[image]
**3.** Once confirmed, it directs that information to the view "transact_test", I want this view to handle the update of the database via a new form that is build with the Article model. But it provides the error message : "*didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.*"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very bad practice to upload images on stackoverflow, i was going vote down you but i don't have reputations.. I just wanna suggest you to avoid to upload images, upload your code in text format,  We all are not able to copy your code..

Answer (score 0):

To fix your error: In transact_test you are just calling render in the request.method == 'POST' block:

```
render(request, ...)
```

You need to return render:

```
return render(request, ...)
```

You should really take a look at some additional django tutorials you are making this harder than you need to. You should almost never manually render a form when using django. And as Tariq said, please don't use images.